# Laravel 5 and redactor file uploads

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using the following code to upload image in Laravel 5 with redactor, nothing happends, Do I need to create form request class for this as well ?

```
Route::post('redactorUpload', function(App\Http\Requests $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->file('file')->move(public_path().'/uploads', $fileName);
    return Response::json(array('filelink' => '/uploads/' . $fileName));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using **Request** class, the static way...i.e.

```
Route::post('redactorUpload', function()
{
    $file = Request::file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file->move(public_path().'/uploads', $fileName);
    return Response::json(array('filelink' => '/uploads/' . $fileName));
});
```

I assume that you have created the form with method "**post**" and action "**redactorUpload**" and enctype to "**multipart/form-data**"

**Example Form :**

```
<form action="redactorUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```